# Sublime3 build system to compile C++ on remote linux box

Tags: c++, ssh, sftp, putty, sublimetext3

[Sublime3](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has scriptable build systems. I'm trying to make a custom one which uses putty & ssh to get to a remote linux box and compile my code there. I would be running sublime in windows and using [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) to keep my code up to date on both machines.

I'm also entirely open to a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working.

Use Plink (you get get it from the putty website) and use it in the shell_cmd arguments:

```
"shell_cmd": "plink.exe <remote server> -l <username> -pw <password> \"cd <your project location> && make\""
```

I'm working from my Linux box at the moment, so that may not be the exact command - leave a comment if you're struggling and I'll get the exact syntax